# WPF DataGrid not picking up CollectionChanged events?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

So I have this DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=../DesignData/ValidationMessages.xaml}" DataContext="{Binding Messages, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Name="Grid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Message}" Header="Message"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ControlID}" Header="ID"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and I have this property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ValidationMessage> Messages = new ObservableCollection<ValidationMessage>();
```

and I have this code:

```
Messages.Add(message);
```

And the DataGrid doesn't show changes. It should, right? I feel like I've done this a million times, but for some reason it's not working.

I have set the DataContext of the whole control to be its own code-behind, no luck. I've tried messing with the BindingMode of the bindings, nothing.

When I inspect the DataGrid during execution, it shows the Items count to be 0.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong, or what I can try?

Comment: are you changing the Messages collection itself at any point?  (is there some other `Messages = something;` somewhere else?)  do you otherwise mess with the itemssource or datacontext in code anywhere?  Are you seeing any binding warnings/errors in the output window?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your code but this works.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Name="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Message}" Header="Message"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ControlID}" Header="ID"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

ObservableCollection<ValidationMessage> Messages = 
    new ObservableCollection<ValidationMessage>();
this.DataContext = Messages;
```

Comment: I have tried that. However, having to set the data context every time isn't really databinding. I'd like to be able to modify the collection when I want and have the bindings refresh. I believe that is the whole point behind using an ObservableCollection. Otherwise, I could just use a list.

Comment: @CamronBute The code above is executed once in Window.Loaded in my test project.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Then my example just does it in the XAML. Any idea why it's not happening?

Comment: @CamronBute Usually this happens when there is a binding error. Did you try to have a look at output window in debug mode. When debugging WPF applications binding errors are displayed at output window.